# MongoDB compass Error creating SSH tunnel: All configured authentication methods failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB. It worked the last time I connected which was a few months ago, but I think I am missing some auth. When I go to recents and press connect, it gives me this error:

```
Error creating SSH Tunnel: All configured authentication methods failed
```

Here is my connection string (with some fields removed for privacy):

```
mongodb://[URL]:27017/[DBname]?readPreference=primary&authSource=admin&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false
```

If I try to make a new connection instead of using recents, it tells me "connection timed out" after about 5 seconds

Comment: Your SSH key or password are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, and enter the passphrase you used at the time of creating your private key. Without the passphrase, you might get the error of no passphrase has been given.